# Como resolver el problema; Na, NaN, Inf Error en R-proyect?

Tags: r

Estoy intentando crear un modelo de regresion entre el peso y la talla de una especies determinada (GHL), dentro de un proyecto (SFE). He filtrado las observaciones de mi especie en una tabla aparte para poder trabajarla mas facilmente.

Mi problema es que al intentar crear mi modelo de regresion me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...)
> :    NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

He comprobado que mis variables son numericas y que ninguna de ellas contiene valores definidos como NA, NaN o Inf.

¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Aqui dejo el script que he corrido hasta ahora:

```
f0
2 = data.frame(read.table('D_BIO_ALLsp_SFWSFE_02-19.csv', header=TRUE, sep=","))
GHL<- filter(f02, project == "SFE")
GHL$weight = GHL$weight /GHL$indnumb
GHL$ln.w = log(GHL$weight)
GHL$ln.size.m= log(GHL$length)
class(GHL$ln.w)
class(GHL$ln.size.m)
fit <-lm(GHL$ln.w ~ GHL$ln.size.m)

Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

Gracias de ante mano

---

La estructura de los datos serian:

> str(GHL)

```
'data.frame':   16702 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ year         : int  2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 2007 ...
 $ ship         : chr  "PA" "PA" "PA" "PA" ...
 $ trip         : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ haul         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ key          : chr  "0E3A902A-292E-4D51-AA0C-8A0C4E35AA55" "0E3A902A-292E-4D51-AA0C-8A0C4E35AA55" "0E3A902A-292E-4D51-AA0C-8A0C4E35AA55" "0E3A902A-292E-4D51-AA0C-8A0C4E35AA55" ...
 $ subgear      : chr  "Both Codends" "Both Codends" "Both Codends" "Both Codends" ...
 $ code         : chr  "COD" "COD" "COD" "COD" ...
 $ species      : chr  "Gadus morhua" "Gadus morhua" "Gadus morhua" "Gadus morhua" ...
 $ subdiv       : chr  "All" "All" "All" "All" ...
 $ subsampleType: chr  "All" "All" "All" "All" ...
 $ kg           : num  37.7 37.7 37.7 37.7 37.7 ...
 $ subsampleW   : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ sex          : chr  "M" "M" "U" "F" ...
 $ length       : num  42 46 13 36 35 35 23 22 7 41 ...
 $ weight       : num  0.69 0.86 0.0158 0.48 0.37 ...
 $ Maturity     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ count        : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ indnumb      : int  56919 56911 56946 56912 56891 56904 56929 56922 56944 56889 ...
 $ GonadWeight  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ id.2         : chr  "2007_5_PA_1" "2007_5_PA_1" "2007_5_PA_1" "2007_5_PA_1" ...
 $ project      : chr  "SFE" "SFE" "SFE" "SFE" ...
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: El problema son los datos. Primero que nada, comparte la salida de `str(GHL)` para saber al menos la estructura, luego revisa si hay NA en `any(is.na(GHL$ln.w));any(is.na(GHL$ln.size.m))`

Comment: Ya comprobe que no hubiera valores con NA, NaN o Inf en mis datos

Comment: El problema creo que viene por datos de tipo inf u otro tipo. Producto de hacr el logaritmo de una variable que podría tener como parámetro el valor 0 si bien no puedo ver el resultado de: GHL$ln.w = log(GHL$weight), mi sugerencia es que podría utilizar otra variable "weight" solo por ejemplo y si la misma te deja hacer el .fit entonces se trata del log()

Comment: Revisaría `any(GHL$indnumb==0)` y lo que ya te dijeron `any(GHL$weight <= 0)`

Comment: He probado a comprobar que weight e indnumb tienen, valores iguales a 0, por eso mismo me saldra el error al realizar el logaritmo. Voy a filtrar los valores y ver si puedo seguir con el modelo

Comment: Solucionado muchisimas gracias :)